# eapply over columns of data frames in environment

Tags: r

I am trying to `eapply` over an environment.

I want to remove all the "symbols" from the column names, therefore standardising them.

The code I have is:

```
eapply(dataEnv, function(x) gsub(paste(symbols, ".", sep = ""), "", colnames(x)))
```

I get this message:

```
> eapply(dataEnv, function(x) gsub(paste(symbols, ".", sep = ""), "", colnames(x)))
$AAPL
[1] "AAPL.Open"     "AAPL.High"     "AAPL.Low"      "AAPL.Close"    "AAPL.Volume"   "AAPL.Adjusted"

$GOOG
[1] "Open"     "High"     "Low"      "Close"    "Volume"   "Adjusted"

$MSFT
[1] "MSFT.Open"     "MSFT.High"     "MSFT.Low"      "MSFT.Close"    "MSFT.Volume"   "MSFT.Adjusted"

Warning messages:
1: In gsub(paste(symbols, ".", sep = ""), "", colnames(x)) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In gsub(paste(symbols, ".", sep = ""), "", colnames(x)) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In gsub(paste(symbols, ".", sep = ""), "", colnames(x)) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How can I tweek the code to get it working?

Data:

```
    require(PerformanceAnalytics)
    library(quantmod)
    library(data.table)

from <- "2017-01-01"
to <- "2018-12-01"

symbols <- c('GOOG', 'MSFT', 'AAPL')

dataEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols(symbols, from=from, to = to, src = "yahoo", adjust = TRUE, env = dataEnv) 

eapply(dataEnv, function(x) gsub(paste(symbols, ".", sep = ""), "", colnames(x)))
```

EDIT:

I would like to perform a calcualtion within the environment.

the calcualtion is:

```
with(dataEnv$GOOG, ifelse(GOOG.Close >= GOOG.Open, 1, 0))
```

Which gives me a a result of 0s and 1s.

My current attempt it:

```
data <- eapply(dataEnv, function(x){
  as.data.frame(x) %>% 
    rename_all(function(n){
      gsub("^(\\w+)\\.", "", n, perl = TRUE)
    })
    lapply(x, 2, function(z) ifelse(z$close >= z$open, 1, 0))

})
```

Comment: Use `stringi::stri_replace` or `stringr::str_replace` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works: using `dplyr`

```
eapply(dataEnv, function(x){
    as.data.frame(x) %>% 
        rename_all(function(n){
            gsub("^(\\w+)\\.", "", n, perl = TRUE)
        })
})
```

Note: I am sure there's a better way to do this, but right now I can't think of how to simply apply the function in place and not create a list... so workaround is to re-generate an environment?:

```
dataEnv <- as.environment(eapply(dataEnv, function(x){
    as.data.frame(x) %>% 
        rename_all(function(n){
            gsub("^(\\w+)\\.", "", n, perl = TRUE)
        })
}))
```

Comment: This is great, anyway I can keep the data in the `env`? The next line I would like to run is `data <- do.call(merge, eapply(dataEnv, Ad))`

Comment: Thanks! you have helped a bunch, I had made an edit to the original post to show what I am trying to achieve (ultimately).

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, we can rename the columns and create a new column comparing `Open` and `Close`

```
eapply(dataEnv, function(x){
    df <- as.data.frame(x)
    names(df) <- sub(".*\\.", "", names(df))
    df$new_col <- as.integer(df$Close > df$Open)
    df
})

#$AAPL
#               Open     High      Low    Close    Volume Adjusted new_col
#2017-01-03 112.2816 112.7955 111.2732 112.6210  28781900 111.2870       1
#2017-01-04 112.3301 112.9700 112.2331 112.4949  21118100 111.1624       1
#2017-01-05 112.3979 113.3094 112.2913 113.0670  22193600 111.7277       1
#2017-01-06 113.2318 114.5699 112.9312 114.3275  31751900 112.9733       1
#2017-01-09 114.3663 115.8013 114.3566 115.3747  33561900 114.0081       1
#2017-01-10 115.1614 115.7528 114.7056 115.4910  24462100 114.1230       1
#....
```